# vue.js 2 img tag lost after re-render ( fetch again ) data from server

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, ecmascript-5

I working with vuejs on my project go on fine until i meet this issue : i have my page to show data grid with image carousel "Owl carousel" and the code look like below :

```
fetchData: async function () {
    let self = this
    let query = self.$route.query

    if ($.inArray(self.rowPerPage, self.selectChoice) !== -1) {
      query['rowPerPage'] = self.rowPerPage
    } else {
      query['rowPerPage'] = 5
    }

    query['page'] = self.page

    /*Get Properties*/
    HTTP.get('property/search', {
      params: query,
      headers: {'pointer-access-token': window.$cookies.get('pointer-access-token')}
    }).then(function (data) {

      let date = new Date();
      let testTime = data.data.data[0].created_at

      self.properties = data.data.data
      self.pages = data.data.pages
      self.rowPerPage = data.data.rowPerPage

    });
  }
```

code above to read data from server and code below is html that i re-render :

```
<div class="listing-item share-list-container" v-if="properties"
             v-for="(property,propertyIndex) in properties">
  ...
  <div class="listing-carousel">
    <div v-for="photo in property.photo">
   <img v-lazy="domainName + photoPath + photo" :alt="property.projectName">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

"img" tag was disappear after DOM was loaded, it wasn't lost from all item, this tag lost 1 or 2 on most items and some items still have this image tag.i really have clue about this.

Thank for idea !

Answer (score 0):

cast the image path to string from your server

Comment: localhost:8081/img/bg1.jpeg

Comment: image is loaded from backend server

Comment: then call the path inside image tag 

<img src="localhost:8081/img/bg1.jpeg">

Comment: thank for idea ! but i found slider "listing-carousel" is cause of problem.when i change slider it work well.